# How to choose model parameters using `Piecewise` function

Tags: dynamic, conditional, piecewise

The following `code` (developed by m_goldberg) works as expected. The model parameters can be selected by using `Button`, being instrumental in conducting a large number of simulations.

Given:

```
SeedRandom[124];
n = 5;
tags = Range[n];
vLabels = {1 -> AGR, 2 -> FIS, 3 -> CO1, 4 -> CO2, 5 -> MA1};
AA = RandomInteger[5, {n, n}];
BB = RandomInteger[5, {n, n}];
{RB[1] = 0.9, RB[2] = 0.5, RB[3] = 0.35, RB[4] = 0.48, RB[5] = 0.15};
{eRB[1] =0.55, eRB[2] = 0.44, eRB[3] = 0.70, eRB[4] = 0.25, eRB[5]=0.65};
muAVE = {0.48, 0.55, 0.53, 0.5, 0.33};
muKSA = {0.87, 0.87, 0.97, 0.89, 0.45};
btnLbl = SetterBar[#, {0, 1}] &;

DynamicModule[{gr, mu, gg, rr, AAg, BBr, γ, μ, scenarioMU},
scenarioMU = ConstantArray[1, n]; 
gr[i_] := eRB[i] RB[i] γ[i];
mu[i_] := scenarioMU[[i]] μ[i]; (*[1] This line needs to be revised.*)
Set[γ[#], 0] & /@ tags;
Set[μ[#], 0] & /@ tags;   (*[2] This line also needs to be revised.*)
Manipulate[
scenarioMU = muKSA - (muKSA - muAVE)/b;
gg = DiagonalMatrix[Table[1 + gr[i], {i, n}]];
rr = DiagonalMatrix[Table[1 + mu[i], {i, n}]];
Column[
  {Dynamic[
     TableForm[
       {Button[btnLbl[γ[#]], γ[#] = Mod[γ[#] + 1, 2],
          Appearance -> None] & /@ tags,
        Button[btnLbl[μ[#]], μ[#] = Mod[μ[#] + 1, 2],
          Appearance -> None] & /@ tags},
        TableHeadings -> {{"γ", "μ"}, tags /. vLabels}]],
   Spacer[36],
   Dynamic[
     TableForm[{gr /@ tags, mu /@ tags}, 
       TableHeadings -> 
         {{"Output growth rate (γ)", "Markup (μ)"}, tags /. vLabels}]],
   Spacer[36],
   Dynamic[gg.AA // MatrixForm],
   Spacer[36],
   Dynamic[rr.BB // MatrixForm]}],
{{b, 10, "Markup\nscenario (b)"}, 0.1, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
TrackedSymbols :> {b, γ, μ}]]
```

I tried to make an adjustment in the above `code` by replacing the commands `[1] and [2]` shown in the above `code` with a `Piecewise` function:

```
If[Set[μ[#],0]&/@tags, μ[i_]:=muKSA[[i]], μ[i_]:=scenarioMU[[i]]];
```

This does not work. Is there any other way to do what I am trying to do? I do not have to use `If[...]` statement, and anything working would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also

```
mu[i_] := muKSA[[i]] (1 - μ[i]) + scenarioMU[[i]] μ[i];
```

will work.

Comment: I liked your formulation of the function `mu[i_]`, which is more transparent and simple to understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TugrulTemel. It also evaluates faster than your method, although the differende in speed is so small that the higher speed of the this method makes no practical difference. in your application.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to my own question, which is:

```
mu[i_] := Piecewise[{{muKSA[[i]], μ[i] ==0}, {scenarioMU[[i]], μ[i] ==1}}];
```

Comment: Excellent! It is always good when you are able to solve your own  problem.